# Binary search saying 0 Numbers are found?

Tags: c++

I am working on a project where I use a Binary search to look through a vector. When I output the data linear search completes properly but Binary search does not.

The output:
------ Data source: 132 unique random numbers ------
    80    81    67    20   187
    90    53    13   103   100
    83    11   198   124   171
    52    68     2   130   172
    50    65   102    38   117
   196   127   140    22    42
    99   120     9   158   115
   192   169    43   186    69
   176    55   182    15   143
    37    23   151    41   164
    48    77   183     1    54
    79     5   199    93   141
    33   150   162    56   110
    24     6   173    44   154
    78    85   112   200   144
   166    72   195   126    35
    64   193   177    47   131
    94    88   137    96    95
   160   122   111   165   108
    49   184     4   116    66
   138     8   142    16    63
   148    57    70   170    21
    59   159   139    75    58
   174   180    25   152   132
   121   194    82   190    71
   181    97    10   106    39
   178    46
------ 100 random numbers to be searched: ------
    66   158    40   148    80
   160   146   112   154   128
     2   166   180   177   183
   179     9    78    83    24
   107   162    54   149    84
   134     9   151   200   179
   197    18   137    37   117
   168   196    62    79   102
   142    32    67   121     8
     1    51   168    78    85
   191   136    46   196    85
    81   130    45    31    81
    23   180    98   159    16
   166   126   163    28   156
    64   121   187    82    41
   147    83    44   114   112
   128   105    48   126    52
    84   158   181   128   141
    62   102   120   111    61
    87    77   138    49    56

Linear search: 100 numbers are found. The average number of comparisons in each search: 52

Binary search: 0 numbers are found. The average number of comparisons in each search: 7

------- numbers in data source are now sorted ---------

Linear search: 100 numbers are found. The average number of comparisons in each search: 47.41

Binary search: 0 numbers are found. The average number of comparisons in each search: 7

```
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iomanip>
  #include <vector>

  const int DATA_SIZE = 200;
  const int DATA_RANGE = 200;
  const int DATA_SEED = 9;
  const int SEARCH_SEED = 17;

  using namespace std;


  int linear_search(const vector<int>& inputVec, const int x, int& 
  comparisons) {
  comparisons = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < inputVec.size();i++)
  {
    comparisons++;
    if (x == inputVec[i])
        return i;
    if (x >= inputVec.size())
        return 0;
   }
   }

   int binary_search(const vector<int>& inputVec, const int x, 
   int& comparisons) {
   int mid = 0;
   int beg = 0;
   int end = inputVec.size();
   comparisons = 0;

   for (size_t x = 0; beg <= end; x++) {
    mid = (end + beg) / 2;
    comparisons++;
    if (x == inputVec[mid]) {
        return x;
    }
    else if (x < inputVec[mid])
        end = mid-1;
    else
        beg = mid+1;
   }
    return -1;
 }

  void print_vec(const vector<int>& vec) {
  vector<int>::const_iterator begin = vec.begin();
  int line = 0;
  cout << setw(6);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); begin++,i++)
  {
    if ((*begin / 5) < 1)
        cout << *begin << setw(6);
    else if ((*begin / 10) == 5)
        cout << *begin << setw(6);
    else 
        cout << *begin << setw(6);
    line++;
    if (line == 5){
        line = 0;
        cout << endl;
        cout << setw(6);
    }

   }
 }

 void average_comparisons(const vector<int>& inputVec, const 
 vector<int>& searchVec, int(*search)(const vector<int>&, const 
 int, int&)) {
 int i, comparison = 0, sum = 0, found = 0;
 int res = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < (int)searchVec.size(); i++) {
    res = search(inputVec, searchVec[i], comparison);
    sum += comparison;
    if (res >= 0)
        found++;
   }
  cout << found << " numbers are found. The average number of 
  comparisons in each search: " << (double)sum / 
  (double)searchVec.size() << endl << endl;
  } 

  int random_number() {
  return rand() % DATA_RANGE + 1;
 } 


int main() {

// -------- create unique random numbers ------------------//
vector<int> inputVec(DATA_SIZE);
srand(DATA_SEED);
generate(inputVec.begin(), inputVec.end(), random_number);
sort(inputVec.begin(), inputVec.end());
vector<int>::iterator it = unique(inputVec.begin(), 
inputVec.end());
inputVec.resize(it - inputVec.begin());
random_shuffle(inputVec.begin(), inputVec.end());

cout << "------ Data source: " << inputVec.size() << " unique 
random numbers ------" << endl;
print_vec(inputVec);
cout << endl;

// -------- create random numbers to be searched ---------//
vector<int> searchVec(DATA_SIZE / 2);
srand(SEARCH_SEED);
generate(searchVec.begin(), searchVec.end(), random_number);

cout << "------ " << searchVec.size() << " random numbers to be 
searched: ------" << endl;
print_vec(searchVec);
cout << endl;

cout << "Linear search: ";
average_comparisons(inputVec, searchVec, linear_search);
cout << "Binary search: ";
average_comparisons(inputVec, searchVec, binary_search);

sort(inputVec.begin(), inputVec.end());
cout << "------- numbers in data source are now sorted ---------" 
<< endl << endl;
cout << "Linear search: ";
average_comparisons(inputVec, searchVec, linear_search);
cout << "Binary search: ";
average_comparisons(inputVec, searchVec, binary_search);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: In the `binary_loop` function, the variable `x` is getting shadowed. Rename the variable in the loop to something else.

Comment: And, in addition to shadowing, the `for` loop in the binary_search function doesn't make any sense. Furthermore, every self-respecting C++ compiler will issue a warning for the linear search function. The linear search function is also broken as well.

Comment: Binary search isn't going to work on a randomly shuffled container so running it before the sort doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out both `linear_search` and `binary_search` are flawed in your code. I recommend you to take a look at a [proper binary search implementation](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/BinarySearch.java.html). It is in Java, but understanding it shouldn't be a problem. Other than that, your array must be sorted in ascending order, otherwise binary search won't work.

If you are interested in further details about the algorithm, I highly encourage you to search for the authors of the source code linked above.